# Identity creates additional foreign key without relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I've implemented Identity 2.0 in my app but am unable to get the logins and claims to tie in with my application user class. I'm using the following to generate the tables (and keys):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().HasKey<int>(l => l.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
```

Each of the tables creates an additional column of ApplicationUser_Id in addition to the UserId column that is already there, when storing new claims via:

```
    await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, tokenClaim);
```

The UserId field is filled with the correct User Id but ApplicationUser_Id remains blank, thus when I retrieve the user there are no claims or logins associated with it. How can I correct this?

Comment: Are you using identityDbContext? or did you create your own DbContext?

Comment: Ah, it's my own and I've neglected to inherit from IdentityDbContext, that'll probably be the problem.

Comment: Probably that is the problem. Usually the EF creates that ApplicationUser_ID when a table relationship is not done correctly. To me happened in the ApplicationRole_ID because i forgot to metion a many-to-many relationship correctly between Roles and a Table of my own. Dig it up and you'll probably find that there is a flawed relationship between your user table and another. Good luck